# Expandable List view child item selection in android?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

In expandable list view set the data based on the parent. In this parent has child item selection, the selection set image view for each child item selection. But in this selection set the other parents child items.

**Below code for parent value set.**

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(final int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
        if(view==null){
            groupViewHolder=new GroupViewHolder();
            view=((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.category_listview_group_item,null);
            groupViewHolder.name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_name);
            groupViewHolder.nameIcon=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_icon);
            groupViewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.categoryImageProgressBarlist);
            groupViewHolder.rigtharrow=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_onclick);
            view.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        } else {
            groupViewHolder=(GroupViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        groupViewHolder.nameIcon =itemImage(view, R.id.category_listview_item_icon, data.get(i).getImageUrl(), groupViewHolder.progressBar);
        groupViewHolder.name.setText(data.get(i).getName());
        return view;
    }
```

**Below code for child item value set**

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b,  View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
        String[] spinnerCount = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
        if(view==null) {
            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
            view = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.category_listview_child_item,null);
            childViewHolder.childName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_child_item_name);
            childViewHolder.childNamePrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_child_item_price);
            childViewHolder.childNameIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_child_item_icon);
            childViewHolder.spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);


           view.setTag(childViewHolder);

        }
        else {
            childViewHolder=(ChildViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }


        childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!childViewHolder.childNameIcon.isSelected()) {
                    childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.yellow_circle_list_item);
                    childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setSelected(true);
                    //  childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setTag(R.mipmap.yellow_circle_list_item);
                    String quantity = childViewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Products product = data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1);
                    product.setQuantity(quantity);
                    dataHandler.addTempproducts(product);
                } else {
                    childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.black_circle_list_item);
                    childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setSelected(false);
                    //  childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setTag(R.mipmap.black_circle_list_item);
                    dataHandler.removeTempProducts(data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1));
                    Products product = data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1);
                    product.setQuantity("1");
                 }
            }
        });


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerCount);
        childViewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        childViewHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                String spinnerCount = childViewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Products product = data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1);
                ArrayList<Products> productList = new ArrayList<Products>();
                productList = dataHandler.getTempproducts();
                if (childViewHolder.childNameIcon.isSelected()) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < productList.size(); k++) {
                        if (data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1).getId() == productList.get(k).getId()) {
                            productList.get(k).setQuantity(spinnerCount);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    product.setQuantity(spinnerCount);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });


  childViewHolder.childName.setText(data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1).getName());
        if(data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1).getPrice().isEmpty()) {
            childViewHolder.childNamePrice.setText(data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1).getPrice());
        } else {
            childViewHolder.childNamePrice.setText(data.get(i).getProductsList().get(i1).getPrice()+"/-");
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Please Help me , i am struct here.......

Comment: Please express your question more clearly,and show your code.

Comment: `In expandable list view set the data based on the parent. In this parent has child item selection, the selection set image view for each child item selection. But in this selection set the other parents child items`. As asked before: rephrase your text. We don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: childViewHolder.childNameIcon.setOnClickListener image view is set in childNameIcon while click the image set the background color as yellow and again click the same image view set the background color as brown, while i click the first time the image is background color to change the yellow, but here yellow color is set into another parent last child item also, this is my problem

Comment: i select the child item in a parent group, that selection to be set into another parent child item also. this is problem.